# Google Map: How to avoid google map usage limit of 25000 maps load per day

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have Four websites each running on different server and using gogole maps api. I want to avoid google usage limit of 25000 maps load per day.

I have below doubts on usage limit. please clear my doubts on below points.

if i am using same api key to load map on my four website then the limit quota of 25000 maps load per day is combined quota for all four websites or will it be for single website??

if i created 4 unique api keys from single google account then can i use each unique key for each website to have 25000 maps load per day for each website.

or can i use different google account to create multiple keys and using each key for each website  to have 25000 maps load per day for each website??

will google will ever come to know if i cheat and try to avoid their usage limit??

Thanks,

Comment: Will Google ever come to know if I post on the internet asking how to cheat on their product usage...

Comment: Yes you are right. but how google will know if i make four different keys from four different accounts and these keys  belongs to me and i am trying to cheat.

Comment: how comes it a cheat?

Answer (score 1):

First, I don't think you can create more than one API of the same type from the same account. I just tried yesterday and it still seems legit.
Second, if you use 4 different accounts and use them on 4 different sites, that should be ok. You are not violating any policy there.
Lastly, protect your limit. Take precautions against misuse of limits by competitors or hackers. We have a site using Google maps directions api and 20k+ queries to the API are getting fired every 2-3 hours. We are taking precautions against this misuse. We are limiting API calls based on IP and User agents to maximum of 10 calls a minute.